# Are there limitations on Snowflake's split_part function?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

Does Snowflake's `split_part` function have a limit on how large the string or individual delimited parts of the string can be? For e.g. in SQL Server, if any part of the string exceeds 256 bytes, the `parsename` function will return `null`for that part.

I looked [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_part.html), but couldn't find any mention of such limitation

Comment: I do not believe there are such limitations.  You're likely only limited by the size of the original string based on field limits there.

Comment: @MikeWalton That's music to me ears

Comment: I aim to please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that there's no limit close to 256 bytes, I generated a 3MB string with 3 substrings. `split_part()` was able to extract a 1MB string without problem:

```sql
create table LONG_STRING
as
select repeat('abcdefghijk', 100000)||','
  ||repeat('abcdefghijk', 100000)||','
  ||repeat('abcdefghijk', 100000) ls
;

select len(ls)
  , len(split_part(ls, ',', 2))
from LONG_STRING

# 3,300,002 1,100,000
```

Comment: This lends some good support to what Mike said in the comments